# POST Request with AFNetworking 2.0 not working, but working in HTTP Request tester

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've just started using the new `AFNetworking 2.0` API having used the previous versions for a while now. I'm trying to do a bog standard `http POST request`, but sadly I'm not doing too well. This is my current code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : self.usernameField.text,
                             @"password" : self.passwordField.text};

[operationManager POST:@"https:URL GOES HERE" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Now this returns a `JSON` of `(NULL)` and doesn't give me a status code like `404` or something (incidentally how do we attain the status code when using AFN 2.0?). However, when I try the information with a web app like [apikitchen.com](http://apikitchen.com) which tests the `HTTP Post request` for me, it works when I put the username and password in the `param` field. So really my question is, why don't the `parameters` in the `AFN 2.0 parameter property` act in the same way as the `parameters` in the web app? And more generally why aren't the `post request parameters` working for me in `AFN 2.0`?

Thanks for the help in advance,
Mike

**EDIT:** I'm struggling with the implementation of the suggested fix. My Post method now looks like this, but It doesn't make sense to me right now.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username" : self.usernameField.text,
                             @"password" : self.passwordField.text};

operationManager.requestSerializer.queryStringSerializationWithBlock =
^NSString*(NSURLRequest *request,
           NSDictionary *parameters,
           NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    NSString* encodedParams = form_urlencode_HTTP5_Parameters(parameters);
    return encodedParams;
};

[operationManager POST:@"URL HERE" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Which content-type is used? How are the parameters encoded? Can you NSLog the parameters *after* encoding? (requires to debug and break into AF methods). (Most useful would be a packet trace, showing the request)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Hi, the content type required by the server is `/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which I believe AF defaults to on `POST requests`. I shall fiddle around with AF later to do the NSLogs you suggested, and will post back when I have an answer.

Comment: OK, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is expected. Now, you may check the body of the request which contains the encoded parameters ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Just checked the body of HTTP without decoding and it's pretty long, not sure how to decode it though to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Decode into `NSDictionary`: [please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306149/nsdictionary-from-name-value-pairs-string/19306633#19306633). You may print the body data as a NSString first (UTF-8).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper struggling with the decoding, it just returns an empty string `<... f6d>" = "";}`. I'm getting the HTTPBody from here: `[operation.request.HTTPBody description]` (Also tried debugDescription) in `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:` in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h`.

Comment: In order to test the AFN's parameter encoding, you need to create a NSString through `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bodyData length:[bodyData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. Print it to the console. _bodyData_ is a NSData object which contains the url-form-encoded parameter string. In order to get the original NSDictionary  parameter back, use the helper function in the link.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I tried the above and it also returned a (Null). It's pretty weird.

Comment: Could you please edit your post, and show the parameter string, encoded by AFNetworking? (since the body is a NSData, please convert it to an UTF-8 encoded string, before showing)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper the UTF-8 encoded string returns (null) so that doesn't work. I can't post the normal parameter string because it contains log in information.

Comment: OK, you need fake parameters, but akin ones, which fails as well. Then, set a breakpoint, in AFURLRequestSerialization.m line 331: `NSString *query = nil;` Step through until the parameters are encoded and the string is set. This string contains the url encoded parameters, and must be properly encoded. If you can't get such a string, then there's no way to figure out what's going on. Print the original parameters (as pair of NSString) and the url encoded string _query_.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper seems the parameters are fine at line 339, but when I do `NSLog(@"Mutable Request: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(__bridge const void *)(mutableRequest.HTTPBody) length:[mutableRequest.HTTPBody length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] );` on line 352, I get a (Null)

Comment: OK. To put it upfront: the corresponding routine `AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding()` and sub-routines which create the url-form-encoded string does not encode according any standard. So, very likely that a server will choke or misinterpret the parameters. Furthermore, there is another potential source of an issue regarding the character-encoding (UTF-8 for example) applied to parameters when they are url-form-encoded. The encoding need to match with the charset parameter of the Content-Type header. The current algorithm doesn't take into account encodings other than ASCII or UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now this returns a JSON of (NULL) and doesn't give me a status code like 404 or something (incidentally how do we attain the status code when using AFN 2.0?).

It should at least give an error. What does the failure handler print out?

> So really my question is, why don't the parameters in the AFN 2.0 parameter property act in the same way as the parameters in the web app? And more generally why aren't the post request parameters working for me in AFN 2.0?

After examining how AFN (Version 2.0.1) encodes the parameters, it appears to me that these aren't encoded as they should: [The application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm).

Until this has been fixed, you may try the following workaround. The following algorithm encodes parameters strictly as suggested by w3c for HTTP 5, at least for Mac OS X 10.8 where I've tested it:

```
static NSString* form_urlencode_HTTP5_String(NSString* s) {
    CFStringRef charactersToLeaveUnescaped = CFSTR(" ");
    CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@~");

    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                         kCFAllocatorDefault,
                         (__bridge CFStringRef)s,
                         charactersToLeaveUnescaped,
                         legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,
                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

(Note: the code above depends on the implementation details of function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`. It's entirely possible to implement the suggested algorithm easily without any dependencies, which I would recommend - it becomes just not that short.)

```
static NSString* form_urlencode_HTTP5_Parameters(NSDictionary* parameters) 
{
    NSMutableString* result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    BOOL isFirst = YES;
    for (NSString* name in parameters) {
        if (!isFirst) {
            [result appendString:@"&"];
        }
        isFirst = NO;
        assert([name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
        NSString* value = parameters[name];
        assert([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);

        NSString* encodedName = form_urlencode_HTTP5_String(name);
        NSString* encodedValue = form_urlencode_HTTP5_String(value);

        [result appendString:encodedName];
        [result appendString:@"="];
        [result appendString:encodedValue];
    }

    return [result copy];
}
```

Then, when using AFN, you can customize the serializing algorithm as shown below:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    operationManager.requestSerializer.queryStringSerializationWithBlock = 
       ^NSString*(NSURLRequest *request,
                  NSDictionary *parameters,
                  NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        NSString* encodedParams = form_urlencode_HTTP5_Parameters(parameters);
        return encodedParams;
    };
```

Comment: Cheers, this is really thorough. I'm going to implement this once I get home and I'll report back. I've marked up for the time being but I'm sure this will be the correct answer as after skimming through it makes sense. Mike

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I'm struggling a little bit with the implementation. Could you check out the revised original post? Cheers.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You need of course helper function `form_urlencode_HTTP5_String()` as well. It should be clear, that this is just a workaround until AFN will fix the form-urlencoding. When sending the request, does the server now answer with a reasonable response?

Comment: Yea I appreciate that this is a temporary fix, however the request now fails with "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." This doesn't seem right as I know the returned JSON starts with a {}. However, I don't even know how to add `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` in AFN 2.0 to see what's going on.

Comment: That means, you got at least something. You should now *confirm* that the server interprets your parameters *correctly*. If this is the case, then this question is finished. Regarding your current error: your are probably not getting JSON. You should check the Content-Type header of the *response*. It's value should be "application/json". It's better to start a new question and provide more info, especially the status code, the MIME type and the content  of the response. If possible (well, it IS possible) print the content in a human readable format (convert NSData to string with UTF-8).

Comment: Well it seems as though the parameters are being encoded correctly as I printed out the string and the uploaded params appear at least to be correct. I'll communicate with the provider of the web service to see if I can't get more information regarding the return type. Question closed and thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can query the _response_ for the MIME type:`NSString* mime = response.MIMEType`. This *should* return `application/json`. It makes sense, to set the "Accept" header of the *request* as well, to "application/json" before you start the connection! Tip: don't be mislead by a super convenient API that networking is easy -- it is still hard   ;)

Comment: Haha, indeed, it is still very hard and AFN 2.0 almost feels like an entirely separate programming language. I've figured out what's wrong. The Content-Type is apparently text/plain. This is because I got an unauthorised response when trying to log in. Sadly this means the web service is not interpreting the parameters correctly.

Comment: The web service should specify which content types it accepts. Perhaps, it accepts JSON. It that case, it would be easy: the body is a JSON (utf-8) containing your params (details shall be specified in API of the web service). Then, set the Content-Type header of the request accordingly to "application/json" in this case and start the connection. (you probably need a different AFN API to setup this kind of request)

Comment: Nope, the API states "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as the content-type. I'm currently talking with the API developers asking why the parameters aren't working.

Comment: Yes, exactly: the "super convenient" APIs like `POST:parameters:..` wrap the parameters into a application/x-www-form-urlencoded body. There's no way to customize the content type. If you had JSON, and want to POST JSON, you can't that with this API. (to be honest, I don't find these API useful at all). BTW: yes, it's good to talk with the web service team, would yield more info. Also, it seems it is time to talk to AFN team as well.

Comment: Oh I see, that's interesting. Just spoken to them and they gave me the wrong sandbox credentials so it turns out that everything is working fine! Do you want to post an issue on the AFN Hub since you have a far greater understanding of the problem, or shall I?

Comment: I would appreciate it, if you could post this issue yourself. If you can now confirm that your original approach (using the built-in parameter form-urlencoding) will NOT work, and my custom form-urlencoded (according w3c spec) DOES work, it would be enough information to post on AFN issues list and ask for clarification. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put `/` after the url. I've missed it for hours.