# AFJSONParameterEncoding in AFNetworking 2.x.x

Tags: ios, rest, paypal, afnetworking-2

I am implementing following paypal REST API:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}' \
-d '{
 "payer_id":"user12345",
 "type":"visa",
 "number":"4417119669820331",
 "expire_month":"11",
 "expire_year":"2018",
 "first_name":"Joe",
 "last_name":"Shopper"
}'
```

I have successfully implement this api in AFNetworking 1.3.3 with following Code. Where `PPWebService` is subclass of `AFHTTPClient`

```
[[PPWebService sharedClient] setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [[PPWebService sharedClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [[PPWebService sharedClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken]];

    [[PPWebService sharedClient] postPath:@"vault/credit-card"
                               parameters:creditCard
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *response = [self JSONToObject:operation.responseString];

        creditCardId = response[@"id"];

        if(creditCardId)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Credit card" message:@"Saved !!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"on" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }
    }
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Credit card" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"on" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }];
```

I want to use AFNetworking 2.x.x in my project. But I am not able to do it with this new version.

I have subclass `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. I search internet and people suggest me to use `AFJSONRequestSerializer`. All other code is very similar. But than also I am getting bad request error.

So how can I send raw JSON string in with POST method in AFNetworking 2.x.x?

**EDIT**

[Code for AFNetworking 2.X.X](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1sfurycnq74irf0/tiunVnOFD_)

**Error Status** : 404 Bad Request

**Response** :

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well formed.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"ab3c1dd874a07"}
```

I am getting proper response by using Postman as shown in following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your attempted code, and the specific error?

Comment: Can you use a tool like charlesproxy to see exactly what you're sending to the server, and add that info to your question too please, as well as the code.

Comment: @ Aaron Brager I have update question with code so please have a look.

Comment: @JosephH Thanks to suggest me that tool. I will use it and come back ASAP.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to UFT8Encode your accessToken, are you doing this elsewhere other than in the code shown?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364080/post-request-with-afnetworking-2-0-not-working-but-working-in-http-request-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got answer. I use subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` to implement API in my project. And use it with singleton object. So this is my singleton method.

```
+ (MASWebService *)APIClient
{
    static MASWebService *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURL];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        _sharedClient = [[MASWebService alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL sessionConfiguration:config];

        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

        _sharedClient.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [_sharedClient.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}
```

The main key line is setting Request Serializer HTTP Header "Content-Type" to "application/json"

If you are not subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager` and using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for single request than also it will work because `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is also conform to `AFURLRequestSerialization` protocol as property of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`. I have not done it but it should look like this.

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];       
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

I hope this will work. Inform me in comment if I am wrong somewhere.

**Source** : [AFNetworking 2.0 POST request working example code snippet](http://techipost.com/2014/07/22/afnetworking-2-0-post-request-working-example-code-snippet/)

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I send raw JSON string in with POST method in AFNetworking 2.x.x?

I had the same issue when trying to use SOAP+XML data with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. Apparently the request serializer should be subclassed to make provision for your special serialisation needs, but this way seems easier:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *envelopeData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:options error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                               URLString:path
                                                              parameters:nil
                                                                   error:&error];
// In my case, I also needed the following: 
// [request setValue:action forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"]; 

[request setHTTPBody:envelopeData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] init];
operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    // parse response here
}
                                          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    // parse response here
}];
```

It hijacks the request serialiser that is created by AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, inserts the parameter data into the HTTP body, and then passes this new request into the AFHTTPRequestOperation.

Comment: I found more simple solution please check my new answer.